# How to set scroll-behavior in Edge?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I want to use scrollLeft method with smooth behavior, but Edge doesn't support it. How can i do it?
Something like 
`menu.scrollBy({ left: 100, behavior: 'smooth' });` but in Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check **Smooth scroll behavior polyfill**. It is supported in **Edge** browser.

The Scroll Behavior specification has been introduced as an extension of the Window interface to allow for the developer to opt in to native smooth scrolling.
Check the repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) or download the polyfill as an [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smoothscroll-polyfill) module.

Example:

```
window.scroll({ top: 2500, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Reference:

[smooth scroll behavior polyfill](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/)